# Can I declare object literals using names rather than of types?

Tags: c++

In JavaScript I would declare an object as:

```
rectangle = {
    length: 4,
    height: 2
}
```

In C++ I do it like this

```
struct Rectangle {
    int length;
    int height;
};

rectangle = Rectangle {
    int {4},
    int {2}
}
```

The C++ style I not as good as the JavaScript style in my opinion, because:

- Types convey less relevant information than names
- properties can not be listed in arbitrary order

Is it possible to declare C++ objects in a way that is more similar to the JavaScript way?

Comment: *"Types convey less relevant information than names*" - Types need good names too, you know.

Comment: If you don't want to make a `Rectangle` struct beforehand and just make an object on its own like in the JS code, you can also do `struct { int length; int height; } rectangle;`. In this case, `rectangle` is of an unnamed type. It's not very common to do that in C++ though as there are usually better solutions for most problems that this is supposed to solve.

Comment: JavaScript and C++ are two *very* different language, with different syntax and semantics. While you can shorten it down in C++ (to e.g. `Rectangle rectangle = { 4, 2 };` which have always been possible) you can't break the rules of the language.

Comment: Javascript does not have oo-types (until recent versions?), so your rectangle is simply an `object` with specific attributes. You can add attribute / members on-the-fly, delete some, etc. which you cannot do in C++, because both languages are different. Do not try to work in C++ the way you work in Javascript, that's not gonna work... And this apply for most existing languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since C++20 you can do:

```
auto rectangle = Rectangle{ .length = 4, .height = 2 };
```

Some compilers have started to support this syntax already, even though C++20 is not released yet.

Comment: That being said, can you list members in an arbitrary way? IIRC you have to initialize the fields in order.

Comment: @Asu No you can't, you have to list them in the order they were declared.

Comment: Just as a side note: Good old C provides more freedom in this respect (since C99) - and designated initialisers, as this feature is called, are already fully specified at least since C90 (but then with same restrictions as in C++20).

Answer (score 4):

From a C++ perspective objects in JavaScript are pairs of two maps (one for properties and another one for internal properties). They can be implemented using some standard containers. This example shows basic implementation for properties map. Access to fields can be improved by using a custom substitution for `std::any` so long casts like `::std::any_cast<double>(` can be avoided. You can even emulate weird js comparison and conversion rules.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <any>
using object = ::std::map<::std::string, ::std::any>;
int main()
{
    object rectangle{{"length", 3.0}, {"height", 2.0}};
    //object rectangle{{"height", 2.0}, {"length", 3.0}}; // Fine too
    ::std::cout << ::std::any_cast<double>(rectangle["length"]) << ::std::endl;
    ::std::cout << ::std::any_cast<double>(rectangle["height"]) << ::std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ii8MGjU5AkXFdluH)

Comment: Worth nothing that, while this is *possible*, it's not a normal C++ idiom

Answer (score 3):

How about you give the paramter classes which represent them like so:

```
struct Height
{
    explicit Height(int h) : height(h) {}

    int height;
};

struct Length
{
    explicit Length(int l) : length(l) {}

    int length;
};

struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(Height h, Length l) : length(l.length), height(h.height) {}

    int length;
    int height;
};


int main()
{
    auto rect = Rectangle(Height(4), Length(5));
}
```

Another nice way to go is the named-parameter-idom where your setters can be chained like this:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle() = default;

    Rectangle& setHeight(int h) { height = h; return *this; }
    Rectangle& setLength(int l) { length = l; return *this; }

    int length;
    int height;
};


int main()
{
    auto namedParameterIdom = Rectangle{}.setHeight(4).setLength(1);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a very good example of using such constructions... Having / using unit-types is great, but differentiating height and length which are both, well,  lengths is not IMHO.

Comment: @Holt I would consider this to be an attribute type and not a unit type. Length and Height are different attributes. But you are right, that there are reasons against such a construct.

Comment: @Holt it would be a mistake to build a wall of length 20 metres and height 3145 km

Comment: If you want to use such a construct to prevent errors, then you should also think about enforcing that usage by making the constructors of `Height` and `Length` `explicit`. Otherwise you can end up in a mixture between `Rectangle(4, 5)` and `Rectangle(Height(4), Length(5))` and that could be really confusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto rectangle = Rectangle{4, 2};
```

is possible, from C++11.

We call it *list initialisation*: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization